# Can hook_civicrm_links create links beside rows of a contact's Events tab?

Tags: hooks, developer, links

I've looked at CRM/Event/Selector/Search.php to see it creating the View/Edit/Delete links, but am just unsure how to make this work. Can someone advise what the appropriate $objectName and $op should be? I'd like to do something like this:

```
function testmodule_civicrm_links( $op, $objectName, $objectId, &$links, &$mask, &$values ) {

  switch ($objectName) {
    case ???:  //Event or Contact perhaps?

      switch ($op) {
        case ???:  //a participant selector perhaps?

            $links[] = array(
                'name' => ts('Send Invoice'),
                'title' => ts('Send Invoice'),
                'url' => 'civicrm/activity/email/add',
                'qs' => 'action=add&reset=1&cid=%%cid%%&selectedChild=activity&atype=3&pid=%%id%%'
              );
          break;
      }
  }
}
```

Where %%id%% comes in from the context of that row in the grid. If I can't get there with a hook, would it be prudent to extend CRM_Event_Selector_Search and override the links function with my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$op = 'participant.selector.row';
$objectName = 'Participant';

The hook is called from CRM_Core_Action::formLink

search for the above string in CRM/Event/Selector/Search.php, and the last couple of arguments gives the needed values which is then passed on to the hook